# ldapadd: invalid format (line 19) entry: "" . Need help

Tags: server

**Command:**

```
sudo ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f custom_schema.ldif
```

**Output:**

```
adding new entry "cn=my_custom_schema,cn=schema,cn=config"

ldapadd: invalid format (line 19) entry: ""
```

**custom_schema.ldif content:**

```
dn: cn=my_custom_schema,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: my_custom_schema

attributetype ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8 NAME 'employeeID'
  DESC 'Employee ID'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.9 NAME 'jobTitle'
  DESC 'Job Title'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.10 NAME 'department'
  DESC 'Department'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

objectclass ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.8 NAME 'employee'
  DESC 'Employee'
  SUP inetOrgPerson
  MAY ( employeeID $ jobTitle $ department ) )
```